# NestJS - Dynamic Data Access Object service/provider

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

**Scenario**

I'm trying to implement 3 level for APIs, controller -> Service -> DAO.
As I don't want to create entity per module, and DAO will be dynamic.

**Current Implementation**

I want to have service/provider inside service which will dynamically instantiate based on which database model I pass.

e.g

I can have Module1, Module2 etc.
Inside Module1

module1.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './module1.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

@Get()
  getHello(): Promise<any> {
    return this.appService.getHello();
 }
}
```

module1.service.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {    
  constructor(
    @Inject('DB_CONNECTION') private db: any
  ) {}

   async getHello(): Promise<any> {
     const dao = this.daoService(this.db.h_users);
     // execute methods of dao and return result
     return ""
    }
  }
```

module1.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './module1.controller';
import { AppService } from './module1.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class Module1Module {}
```

My DatabaseModule

database.provider.ts

> init-models is from sequelie-auto

```
      import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
      import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
      import { initModels } from '../models/init-models';

      export const databaseProviders = [
        {
          inject: [ConfigService],
          provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
          useFactory: async (config: ConfigService): Promise<Object> => {
            try {
              const sequelize = new Sequelize(
                config.get('DB_NAME') || '',
                config.get('DB_USER') || '',
                config.get('DB_PASS') || '',
                {
                  dialect: config.get('DB_DIALECT') || 'mysql',
                  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
                  port: config.get('DB_PORT') || 3006,
                  define: {
                    timestamps: true,
                  },
                  pool: {
                    max: 5,
                    min: 0,
                    idle: 20000,
                  },
                },
              );
              const db = initModels(sequelize);

              return db;
            } catch (error) {
              throw error;
            }
          },
        },
      ];
```

Now I've common DAO which have multiple method which is like wrapper on sequelize methods

dao.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

/**
 * Class reperesnt the Generic Data Acceess Object
 */
@Injectable()
export class DAOService {
  /**
   * @param {string} model - sequalize model
   */
  declare model;
  constructor(model: any) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  /**
   * Get a single record for specified model by unique idenntifier
   */
  getRecordById = async (id: number) => {
    try {
      if (id) {
        const record = await this.model.findOne({ where: { id: id } });
        if (record !== null) {
          return { success: true, data: record };
        }
      } else {
        return { success: false };
      }
      return { success: false };
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  };
}
```

database.module.ts

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { databaseProviders } from './database.provider';
import { databaseProvider2 } from './database.provider2';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  providers: [...databaseProviders],
  exports: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

**Issue**

I'm not able to figure out how to exactly move forward, I've tried to inject DAOService but it gives error.

If I do

database.module.ts

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { DAOService } from './dao.service';
import { databaseProviders } from './database.provider';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  providers: [...databaseProviders, DAOService],
  exports: [...databaseProviders, DAOService],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

And try to inject and use inside Module1 service, I can't use it as I want to

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DAOService } from '../database/dao.service';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  // private daoService: DAO;
  constructor(
    @Inject('DB_CONNECTION') private db: any,
    private daoService: DAOService,
  ) {}

  async getHello(): Promise<any> {
    const r = this.daoService(this.db.h_users);
    // const r = await this.daoService.getAllRecords(1, 10, 1, 'DESC', '', {});
    // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(r, null, 2));
    return r;
  }
}
```

Error

```
src/Module1/module1.service.ts:13:26 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
Type 'DAOService' has no call signatures.
```

**Goal**

My only goal is to have instantiate or have dynamic DAO based on which database model I pass and use it inside service and if possible I want to have DAOService extended if for some module I want to extend the functionality.

Comment: Seriously, why are you making NestJS so complicated?

Comment: @NirajChauhan Well, I don't want to use Sequelize objects directly model.find etc, and what's wrong creating wrapper which acts as helper/util functions which can take care of all small things like logging and etc?
Also it doesn't make sense for me to create such wrappers for each schema better have one dynamic. 
If you have alternative please feel free to tell me, my only goal here is to have wrapper which should be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to NestJS, but this is how I use a service inside another, maybe it can help

```js
@Injectable()
export class Service1 {
  constructor(
    private DAOService: DAO
  ) {
    this.DAOService.init();
  }
  async myMethod(data: any): Promise<any> {
    await this.DAOService.myDAOFunction(/* param */);
  }
}
/* DAO Service */
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.TRANSIENT })
export default class DAO {
    private obj;
    init() {
        this.obj = new DAO();
    }
    async myDAOFunction(/* param */){
    }
}
```